# Force mobile phone to have a 1000px width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a website which is designed for desktops and laptops however, when viewed on a mobile phone it tries to scale it (as I have a few media queries for different monitor sizes).

Is it possible to force a mobile phone to have the same width as a browser, or trick the css to think that?

Comment: `min-width:1000px` on the body ?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: what if it actually has the same px as the desktop screen? It's going to be scaled at the end (meaning the proportions will be kept). What is the expected view on mobile ?

Comment: The expected view on the mobile is to look how it does on a desktop, but elements are absolutely positioned right, left, top, bottom due to the type of website. So can I make the phone think it is actually 1000px wide?

Comment: when you say "the same width", do you want the entire width to be viewable without scrolling? Or do you want people to scroll to see the rest of the window?

Comment: Erm, I want the page to feel.. zoomed out as if it was a normal none-responsive html website if that makes sense? Sorry if that is rather vague

Answer (score 1):

"Erm, I want the page to feel.. zoomed out as if it was a normal none-responsive html website if that makes sense? Sorry if that is rather vague – Josh Boothe 7 mins ago"

If you want that just remove the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` and dont use media queries.

Answer (score 1):

@karthikr gave you the correct answer.

```
body { min-width: 1000px; }
```

In the sites that I build that are responsive, I always make sure to include the following rule for IE8:

```
.ie8 body { min-width: 990px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this, that might give the effect you are looking for.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=600px">`